# How to set interval and loop sending data to database

Tags: c#

I have problems with my code. I'm trying to send one data to db every loop. Loop function working fine, but the data is not the latest. Its the 1st data I manage to send. so, my db is full of the same data. Here is my code:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int iIdx;
        int[] iData;
        bool[] bData;
        //float[] irData;


        if (m_bRegister) // Read registers (4X references)
        {
            // read register (4X) data from slave
            if (adamTCP.Modbus().ReadHoldingRegs(m_iStart, m_iLength, out iData))
            //if (adamTCP.Modbus().ReadInputRegs(m_iStart, m_iLength, out iData)) // Read registers (3X references)
            {
                m_iCount++; // increment the reading counter
                txtStatus.Text = "Read registers " + m_iCount.ToString() + " times...";
                // update ListView

                for (iIdx = 0; iIdx < m_iLength; iIdx++)
                {
                    listViewModbusCur.Items[iIdx].SubItems[2].Text = iData[iIdx].ToString();            // show value in decimal
                    listViewModbusCur.Items[iIdx].SubItems[3].Text = iData[iIdx].ToString("X04");   // show value in hexdecimal
                }
                //display label and send to DB
                label1.Text = HttpGet("http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/misc/api.php?station=KL&value=" + iData[2].ToString());
            }
            else
                txtStatus.Text = "Read registers failed!"; // show error message in "txtStatus"
        }
```

The "label1.text = httpGet" code is the one i'm trying to send data to. And I want to set 1 minute interval for the data send.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is the usual "access to modified closure" problem.

Comment: How do I write it? I try to re-declare int[] iData but failed.

Comment: Verify you are getting to the HttpGet statement more than once before you investigate other failures.

Comment: I think my code is correct. here is the code:

    static string HttpGet(string url)
        {
            HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(url)
                                 as HttpWebRequest;
            string result = null;
            using (HttpWebResponse resp = req.GetResponse()
                                          as HttpWebResponse)

                return result;
        }